# postresql: использование IF THEN ELSE в DECLARE блоке функции

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, dynamic

есть функция в которой формируется динамически sql для двух вариантов входного параметра - строка, содержащая начинку WHERE, и пустая строка:

код упростил, чтоб тут не захламлять:

```
DECLARE
    
    selected_t TEXT := '
    WITH selected_t AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            mytable_t ' || WHERE $1 || '
    )';

    sql1 TEXT := 'SELECT * FROM selected_t';

    sql2 TEXT := 'SELECT * FROM mytable_t';

BEGIN   

    IF $1 = '' THEN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql2
        USING expr_where;
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE selected_t || sql1
        USING expr_where;
    END IF;
    
END;
```

Чтоб избавиться от дублирования довольно большого кода хотелось бы формирование sql полностью перенести в `DECLATE`.

Попробовал `IF THEN ENDIF` в `DECLARE`, но валятся ошибки или это невозможно и в `DECLARE` я могу только объявить какие-то переменные и инициализировать их без всяких условий, а все условия уже в блоке `BEGIN END`?

**P.S.**
вот такой код не работает

https://dbfiddle.uk/Y9Puo177

выдаётся ошибка

```
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function func_dbg(text) line 80 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 22004
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: *или это невозможно и в DECLARE я могу только объявить какие-то переменные и инициализировать их без всяких условий, а все условия уже в блоке BEGIN END?* Именно так. Секция DECLARE предназначена для определения локальных переменных и присвоения им литерального значения. Никакой код в секции определения не допускается. Впрочем, я в упор не вижу смысла в описанном. Если хочется написать отдельно весь блок присвоения - то вообще не присваивайте значения в секции DECLARE, и весь код присвоения разместите в блоке BEGIN-END. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jrnQ7kk_)

Comment: И да - у Вас просто синтаксическая ошибка. Должно быть не `mytable_t ' || WHERE $1 || '`, а  `mytable_t WHERE ' || $1 || '`

Comment: @Akina. виноват, просто выпиливал много, добавил в конец вопроса кусок кода, но в нем тоже ошибки выдаются :(, похоже пока не въезжаю еще в `DECLARE` блок, что в нем можно писать и как, а что нет

Comment: Пожалуйста, не размещайте огрызки кода. Выкладывайте код, который можно просто скопировать и сразу запустить. Ещё лучше - сделайте минимальный online fiddle с таблицами, примером данных (5-7 строк на таблицу) и требуемым результатом, и дайте ссылку.

Comment: @Akina, понял (просто раньше тут про БД не писал). Вот прописал код https://dbfiddle.uk/Y9Puo177, функция формируется, ошибок нет, но при исполнении та же ошибка, что и у меня.

Comment: Ну ё моё... вот чему у тебя равно `$2` и `$3` в выражении присвоения, а? с учётом того, что у функции ОДИН параметр?

Comment: так я поэтому и написал ранее, что похоже не совсем усваиваю, вот почему-то думалось, что `USING expr_where;` как раз и передает параметры, которые затем превращаются в $1, $2 и т.д., иначе зачем он тут вообще нужен, сейчас понимаю ошибку